# How to reference a data point (or points) in another series in highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have a column chart, which displays two series, with data for a number of years.

Y-axis is a number
X-axis is a year

Each year has a column for each of the series (two).

I want to create a data label for these columns that shows the percentage of the total sum of the value of the two columns (series value) for each year. To do this I need to reference both the current y value and the sum of the two y values in a given catagory (year).

I've tried something like this:

```
          series: {
                dataLabels:{
                    enabled:true,
                    formatter:function() {
                        var pcnt = (this.y / (series[0].y + series[1].y)) * 100;
                        return Highcharts.numberFormat(pcnt) + '%';
                    }
                }
            }
```

In an attempt to use the series index when summing the two and the "this" keyword to reference the y value of the current column, but this does not work (chart does not display and console notes:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: series is not defined

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RG8YT/5/) of my work in progress

And here is a copy of the compelte code I'm trying to implement for this graph

```
$(function () {


     $('#e_74').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        credits: {
        enabled: false
        },
        noData: {
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontSize: '20px'
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Title',
        },
        navigation: {
            buttonOptions:
            {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
              categories: [2013]
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Number of facilities'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:,.0f} </b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0,
                borderWidth: 0
                },
            series: {
dataLabels:{
                        enabled:true,
                        formatter:function() {
                            var pcnt = (this.y / (series[0].y + series[1].y) * 100;
                            return Highcharts.numberFormat(pcnt) + '%';
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{showInLegend: true, name: 'With trained staff', data: [350]}, {showInLegend: true, name: 'Without trained staff', data: [500]}]
        });
    });
```

Comment: var pcnt = (this.y / (series[0].y + series[1].y) * 100;  ) is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the chart within your formatter function using

```
var chartt = $('#e_74').highcharts();
```

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RG8YT/7/) for it. Just in case I am missing something, I left a console.log statement so you can see what and how you can access other data. As a side note, you were also missing a ending parenthesis in your formatter:

```
var pcnt = (this.y / (chartt.series[0].yData + chartt.series[1].yData) * 100);
```

Comment: This looks good but the percentages are coming out as zero still? Hmm it looks like it's necessary to parseInt the yData otherwise it treats them as a string, and then the percentages come out as zero, so I threw in this:

`var sum = parseInt(chartt.series[1].yData, 10) + parseInt(chartt.series[0].yData, 10);`

And used the var sum as a denominator in the percentile calculation - thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Here is [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/RG8YT/8/)

```
        dataLabels:{
                    enabled:true,
                    formatter:function(e) {
                        var ChartX = $('#e_74').highcharts();                            
                        var pcnt = (this.y / (ChartX.series[0].yData[0] + 
                        ChartX.series[1].yData[0]) * 100);
                        return Highcharts.numberFormat(pcnt) + '%';
                    }
                }
```